# Preserving spaces in path variable names

Tags: perl, typescript

I want to open a clip directory. In the directory path, space is there in between. path is stored in the `$pathg` variable.

can please tell me how to open the path or how to add escape character in path using path variable?

```
Path = \\fmsgfxauto4\mediatests$\ATS-MediaTests\Tests\Media\Video\Decoder-Streams\AVC\Suite\VClips\Main_Profile\VC-303-A D-Traffic-AVC-MP\FunctionalTests\V30313_B_D-Traffic_AVC_MP_num_ref_frames_6
```

Code:

```
        opendir (CLIPDIR, $pathg) or die "Couldn't open directory $pathg, $!";
        my $isfound = 0;
        while (my $clip = readdir CLIPDIR and $pathg)
        {
            #if($clip =~ /.264$/)
            if(grep{/.264$/ || /.avc$/ || /.26l$/} "$clip")
            {
```

Comment: Why backslashes in the path? Is this a Windows application? If it is windows, why doesn't the path have a drive specification (i.e., path=`C:\frmsgfxauto4\...`)?

Comment: @mob, It's a Windows UNC path (`\\foo\bar\...`), but `\\ ` is being rendered as `\ ` until the edit is approved

Answer (score 3):

In double-quoted string literals, of the characters present, `\` and `$` need escaping.

```
my $pathg = "\\\\fmsgfxauto4\\mediatests\$\\ATS-MediaTests\\Tests\\Media\\Video\\Decoder-Streams\\AVC\\Suite\\VClips\\Main_Profile\\VC-303-A D-Traffic-AVC-MP\\FunctionalTests\\V30313_B_D-Traffic_AVC_MP_num_ref_frames_6";
```

In single-quoted string literals, of the characters present, `\` may be escaped, but it's only required if it's followed by another `\`.

```
my $pathg = '\\\\fmsgfxauto4\\mediatests$\\ATS-MediaTests\\Tests\\Media\\Video\\Decoder-Streams\\AVC\\Suite\\VClips\\Main_Profile\\VC-303-A D-Traffic-AVC-MP\\FunctionalTests\\V30313_B_D-Traffic_AVC_MP_num_ref_frames_6';
```

or

```
my $pathg = '\\\fmsgfxauto4\mediatests$\ATS-MediaTests\Tests\Media\Video\Decoder-Streams\AVC\\Suite\VClips\Main_Profile\VC-303-A D-Traffic-AVC-MP\FunctionalTests\V30313_B_D-Traffic_AVC_MP_num_ref_frames_6';
```